# jHipster dev profile reverse proxy?

Tags: jhipster

I created a skeleton app with jhipster and added some entitles with `import-jdl`. Now I'm trying to run the dev profile and it hosts it on localhost:8080, which is fine. But I want to proxy it to the public Internet through nginx and put it behind SSL.

Now if I were using Tomcat as an app server, I could set the `proxyHost` property on the `Connector` to tell the app server what its public-facing URL is so it generates URLs for the client properly.

But I don't know what app server jhipster uses for the dev profile or how to configure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go to solve your problem,

The most simplest one is to reverse proxy using nginx, like this:

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name your-domain.com;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/your-app-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/your-app-error.log;

  return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen      [::]:443 ssl;
  listen      443 ssl;
  server_name your-domain.com; 

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/your-app-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/your-app-error.log;

  ssl_certificate     /path/to/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/server.key;

  keepalive_timeout   70;
  add_header          Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/2;
  location    / {
    proxy_pass  http://jhipster;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
}

upstream jhipster {

  server 127.0.0.1:8080;

}
```

which should work on every nginx.

This expects your app running at port 8080 at localhost, what is the case when you start it locally. This furthermore requires you to install java and more stuff on your server.

A better way is to use the docker option to create docker images. There are a lot of ways to handle with docker images, like public repository as DockerHub as well as private solutions, like GitLab Container registry. At least you can do a trick by serving the [registry docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) at some server with ssl, to use this for private registry. 
Then you can at least deploy your app to the same nginx configuration as written above, directing traffic to a running docker container. With this, you only need a arbitrary linux distribution with docker and nginx running.

To gain the power of CI/CD systems, you can deploy these images to complex systems like kubernetes, but also to docker swarm (+ [Docker Shipyard](https://shipyard-project.com/)), or to smaller and easier to setup solutions like [Deis](http://deis.io/) or [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/). You can read [this article](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/09/22/build-cd-pipeline-with-gitlab-gitlab-ci/), which guides you through a setup of GitLab + GitLab CI + Registry + Dokku, where you can deploy your JHipster application using `git push origin master`

***note***: I suggest not to use the dev profile in production. To keep update with your application logs, consider specific logback configuration or solutions as JHipster Console (ELK Stack)

Comment: (1) I already have nginx set up this way. (2) I need to know how to adjust the configuration of Undertow (the dev application server for jhipster) so it's aware of the URL to give to the client in HTTP responses. Currently it's telling the client to fetch from 127.0.0.1 which obviously won't work. (3) This is for a test/QA instance of my app, so dev profile is fine. Production instance will of course use the prod profile.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. The url set in the angular client, or you are working with EMails and got 127.0.0.1 inside, or you are working with HATEOAS and getting 127.0.0.1 for base url? please specify

Comment: Turns out my problem was unrelated to proxy settings. It's working fine now after I regenerated the files from the JDL.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this works. Most important part is upstream.